# Filtering on a formatted datefield

Tags: angularjs

I've started recently with AngularJS, and I've come across this problem.
I'm filtering a list with a Angular Filter object. It all works, but I want to be able to type a date value to filter the date column. Problem is, the date that comes from my webservice is (ofcourse) in another format than the showed date.

Here is an example:
View:

```
Name: <input type="text" ng-model="search.Name"><br>
Date: <input type="text" ng-model="search.Date"><br>
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in filtered = (list | filter:search)">
    <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.Date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.list = [{
      Name: "Item1",
      Date: "2018-08-06T13:43:11.82Z"
    },{
      Name: "Item2",
      Date: "2018-08-05T13:43:11.82Z"
    },{
      Name: "Item3",
      Date: "2018-08-04T13:43:11.82Z"
    },{
      Name: "Item4",
      Date: "2018-08-03T13:43:11.82Z"
    }
  ];

    $scope.search = {};
    $scope.$watch('search', function (newVal, oldVal) {
      $scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.list, newVal);
    }, true);
});
```

working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/O7j1DAzoxArHK4mnjyeP?p=info

How can I alter this, so I can type the date-value as formatted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="search.Name">
    <br>
    Date:
    <input type="text" ng-model="search.Date">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in list2 | filter : search.Date">
        <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.Date}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  const list = [{
    Name: "Item1",
    Date: "2018-08-06T13:43:11.82Z"
  },{
    Name: "Item2",
    Date: "2018-08-05T13:43:11.82Z"
  },{
    Name: "Item3",
    Date: "2018-08-04T13:43:11.82Z"
  },{
    Name: "Item4",
    Date: "2018-08-03T13:43:11.82Z"
  }
    ];
  $scope.list2 = list.map(x => ( 
      { 
        Name: x.Name, 
        Date: $filter('date')(x.Date, 'dd-MM-yyyy')
      })
    );
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't you lose the ability to sort on the date field in that case? Although I could map the "formatted date" to a new property I guess

Comment: List is untouched. You may sort list and then map it. That's just a simple example. You'd like to look [here]( http://plnkr.co/edit/3ePAyW8uZG1GIGBBnsBn?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

At this case you should create `custom` filter:

```js
angular.module('plunker', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.list = [{
    Name: "Item1",
    Quantity: 21,
    Date: "2018-08-06T13:43:11.82Z"
  }, {
    Name: "Item2",
    Quantity: 20,
    Date: "2018-08-05T13:43:11.82Z"
  }, {
    Name: "Item3",
    Quantity: 31,
    Date: "2018-08-04T13:43:11.82Z"
  }, {
    Name: "Item4",
    Quantity: 25,
    Date: "2018-08-03T13:43:11.82Z"
  }];

  $scope.search = {};
}).filter('custom', function() {
  return function(array, search) {
    function Norm(x) {
      return (x + '').toLocaleLowerCase();
    }

    return array.filter(function(x) {
      for (var prop in search) {
        if (prop != 'Date' && search[prop] &&
          Norm(x[prop]).indexOf(Norm(search[prop])) == -1)
          return false;
      }
      if (x.Date) {
        var formatted = x.Date.substring(0, 10).split('-').reverse().join('-');
        if (search.Date && !formatted.startsWith(search.Date))
          return false;
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<body ng-app='plunker' ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  Name: <input type="text" ng-model="search.Name">
  <br> Quantity: <input type="text" ng-model="search.Quantity">
  <br> Date: <input type="text" ng-model="search.Date">
  <br>
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in list | custom : search | orderBy : 'Quantity'">
      <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Quantity}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't know if that would be the most elegant way, since you need to change some things when there are more fields, but it seems to work for this situation. Thank you!

Comment: @Cryothic, check out updated answer, now it works with arbitrary number of fields. Also there is sorting ability of origin array.